# Push sub-repo content together (not using git submodules)

Tags: git, version-control

Inside a main repo, there is another repo (which might have been downloaded from github, i.e.), I call this a sub-repo.

I don't want to use git submodules feature.

The sub-repo might be commited and pushed to his own remote eventually. But I would like to carry on work in the main repo, ignoring that folder (sub-repo) actually is a git repo. But I would like to track the sub-repo content from the main-repo (I was studying the consequences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40567461/track-the-same-files-in-multiple-repositories)).

I was successful in this endeavor until the point where I pushed main-repo commits, when I noticed the sub-repo content wasn't pushed together. Even though I added it when committing.

Using `git ls-files`, I see the folder (sub-repo) is there, but files aren't listed, so I'm not sure the sub-repo content is acctualy being tracked by main-repo.

Using `git ls-tree --full-tree -r HEAD`, I see the sub-repo being called a `commit`, instead of a `blob` as is the case for other files of the main-repo.

Is it possible to push the sub-repo content together?

Comment: To add the sub-repo, I used `git add sub-repo/*` instead of `git add sub-repo`. Now `git ls-tree --full-tree -r HEAD` show sub-repo files are there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried and files in sub-repo can be pushed together with main-repo. The following steps can be refered:

1. Git bash in local main-repo
2. Use `git clone <URL for sub-repo>` to clone the sub-repo under main-repo
3. Use `git status`, you will find a untracked folder sub-repo, then use `git add sub-repo/` and `git commit` to track
4. Add a file, such as new.txt in `/main-repo/sub-repo` directory
5. Use `git add sub-repo/new.txt` and `git commit` (**note:** it’s run in the `/main-repo` directory)
6. Use `git push` to push to remote main-repo, and you can find the file new.txt also there. Also you can use `git ls-files` to find the file

**Note**: You may have noticed that the mode is 160000 if we use `git add sub-repo` and `git commit`, and mode is 100644 if we use `git add sub-repo/` and `git commit`. 1600000 is Gitlink, it means you record a commit as a directory entry rather than a subdirectory or a file, somewhat like submodules. 100644 means regular non-executable file. So you can treat sub-repo as a folder.

Comment: Using `git ls-tree --full-tree -r HEAD` can you confirm the sub-repo was added as `blob` and not as a `commit`? I would like to know which thing determiners one or the other to happen. Did you noticed any difference between `git add sub-repo/` and `git add sub-repo`?

Comment: Yes, the new file's type is blob and exist in main-repo. You may have noticed that the mode is 160000 if we use `git add sub-repo` and `git commit`, and mode 100644 if we use `git add sub-repo/` and `git commit`. 1600000 is Gitlink, it means you record a commit as a directory rather than a subdirectory or a file, somewhat like submodules. 
100644 means regular non-executable file. So you can treat sub-repo as a folder.

Comment: Please include this in the answer with a reference to the 1600000/100644 stuff.

Comment: @KcFnMi, I added it just now. Hope it can help more people :)

Comment: Yep, hope so too ;) - Devil is on  the details. Perhaps a reference for the 1600000/100644 stuff might be helpful also.

Answer (score 1):

The **main-repo** and the *sub-repo* are tracked on the **main-repo**? i.e., While you are at the **main-repo** directory running the `git`'s commands, do you do `git add` to the files both the **main-repo** and to the *sub-repo*?

If yes, then on the **main-repo** you do `git commit` to track both the **main-repo** and the *sub-repo*. And after the `git commit` you must to do `git push` on the **main-repo** to send the **main-repo** and the *sub-repo* to the **main-repo** upstream. This way you are tracking both **main-repo** and *sub-repo* to the **main-repo** upstream.

But this will not automatically track the *sub-repo* with its *sub-repo* upstream. You must to explicitly to do `cd sub-repo` and then `git add`, `git commit` and `git push` on the *sub-repo* to track the *sub-repo* with its *sub-repo* upstream.

For a better insight, I recommend to use a `Visual Git Tool` as Smartgit.

1. http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/

[image]

Comment: Thanks for Visual Git Tool as Smartgit. But the essence of the solution is to add the files, not the sub-repo. I did it as mentioned in the comment above, might not be the better solution.

Comment: You are welcome. However it will not to add the `sub-repo` as is a git sub-module. Every time I mentioned the *sub-repo* I am referring to its files within all of them or just some files. To add a submodule, you need to perform another command, the `git submodule init`. Your **main-repo** is not aware that the *sub-repo* is a another `git-repository`, it thinks it is just another folder within some files. It will only work like this after you add the first file on the *sub-repo* to the **main-repo** with `git add sub-repo/first_file.txt`.

Comment: I saw `sublimetext` tag in your profile, may I ask for a comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40594295/sublime-text-mysql-build-variable-substitution-issue?