# Sublime Text MySQL Build System variable substitution issue

Tags: mysql, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm trying to configure Sublime text to do MySQL build, following is the script:

```
{
    "cmd": ["mysql", "--default-character-set=utf8", "-uuser", "-ppwd", "-hlocalhost", "-v", "db_mine", "-e source main.sql"],
    "selector": "source.sql"
}
```

As it is, it works for file `main.sql`, as presented in the script. Obviously that should be changed, I see people using $file there.

The problem is that here (Windows 7) it's not working.

If I change it to `$file`, then I get:

```
ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\U'.
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Take a look at https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/sublime-build-mysql/10181

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works on macOS:

```
{
    "cmd": ["/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql", "-u", "root", "-e", "source $file", "-t"],
    "selector": "source.sql"
}
```