# Git - Shared directory between multiple repositories

Tags: git, version-control

I have two repositories (Repo1 and Repo2) and a shared directory between them.
Its desired that Repo2 changes when shared directory changes in Repo1.
How can I do this?

Comment: can you explain a little more ? Is the shared directory code based ? Could it be Repo 3 and use submodules ?

Comment: shared directory cant't be Repo3

Answer (score 1):

So you mean files in Repo1 changed can be detected in Repo2 (such as `git status` can find the change)? If it’s your requirement, you can add Repo1 as a submodule for Repo2 by `git submodule add <Repo1’s URL>`.

Comment: I don't want to set Repo1 as a submodule of Repo2. Just a subdirectory of Repo1 should be a submodule of Repo2.

Comment: so you can refer this thread, it can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574373/push-sub-repo-content-together-not-using-git-submodules

Comment: @Mariana, I didn't like submodule solution for my situation. I preferred to make shared directory as a separate Repository. Thanks to you Mariana.

Comment: Did the link I shared in comment help you to solve your situation? This is the way not treat the other repo as submodule.

Comment: Above two ways can deal with Repo1 and Repo2 separately, and I’m not clear why it’s not meet your requirement. There is another way--sbutree, that you can treat a branch in Repo1 as part of Repo2, such as `git subtree add --prefix=Repo1 <URL for Repo1> master`.